# SDK Manager is executing in cmd but not opening

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, java

**Config Details:**

Windows 8 Pro 32bit

adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130717

jdk-6u26-windows-i586 32bit

**Directories:**

For Java - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26

For Android Root - Z:\Program Files\Android

For Android SDK - Z:\Program Files\Android\sdk

**Environmental Variables:**

var_name: JAVA_HOME

var_value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\

var_name: JDK_HOME

var_value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\

var_name: Path

var_value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin

**Modification:**
1)
set java_exe=
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF

2)
for /f %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java.exe" -s') do set java_exe=%%a

3)
for /f %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java.exe" -s -w') do set javaw_exe=%%a

First i downloaded adt-bundle then extracted into Android Root directory (i installed java far earlier) then i installed ADT Plugins from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and successfully connected Eclipse IDE with Android SDK. Now i am trying to Android SDK Components but when i clicked on Window-> Android SDK Manager in Eclipse a dialogue box opened said SDK Manager will open in a while but it didn't. Whenever i try to open SDK Manager everytime a cmd prompt for a second then disappear and nothing happened while AVD Manager open properly.

Then i went through some solution in several forums and modified some line of code (as of modification 1 in tools\android.bat ; 2 and 3 in tools\lib\find_java.bat)

Now in command line

```
Z:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools>android
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is client.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                    see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image

Z:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools>
```

As you can see that my attempts are successful and android.bat is executing but the problem is **when i try to open SDK Manager directly or via IDE again nothing happened but executing in cmd.** I cannot understand what happening actually and i am unable to found anything related with this in any forum. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you open it via cmd, does it return an error?

Comment: No, whenever i tried to open android.bat in cmd it returns some lines which i wrote in code view not anytype of error.

Answer (score 0):

In your PATH environmental variable, move *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin* to the beginning of the collection, and see if that addresses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the directory structure of your sdk installation changed. Try running android.bat from the sdk directory

```
Z:\Program Files\Android\sdk>tools\android.bat
```

If the sdk Manager opens (close it) and set the work_dir in android.bat to the sdk directory. In android.bat change line

```
set work_dir="%cd%"
```

to

```
set work_dir="Z:\Program Files\Android\sdk"
```

or to

```
set work_dir="%~dp0.."
```

If the above does not work try to get more information what is wrong in calling java, output the java call to the console. In android.bat change line

```
call %java_exe% .....
```

to

```
echo call %java_exe% .....
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

android.bat seems to have a problem running from a samba share mounted on my windows system.  This fixes the problem for me.

```
V:\>android
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
[snip]
V:\>c:
C:\Users\me>android
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I found that none of the "set" commands in  beginning of the batch file worked correctly. 
 prog is set to ~f0. 
 work_dir is empty 
 cd /d ~dp0 results in an error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

**Android.bat requires command extensions enabled in order to run correctly.**

Restore the original batch file and edit this line
from...
   setlocal 
to...
  setlocal **enableExtensions**

This should set all the environment variables correctly so that they don't need to be hard coded.

You can also enable command extensions in the registry.  Reboot after making this change. 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\EnableExtensions = 1